# How to change Node.js version on Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have several jobs on Jenkins for launch protractor tests. I'm starting to use `async`/`await` at some points and seems that the default version of Node.js that has Jenkins doesn't handle `async`/`await`.

I prepared a workaround on another pipeline that uses `async`/`await`, but I don't want to use it as a default solution:

```js
nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: "Node 8.11") {
    "npm config ls"
    "node -v"
    "npm"
}
```

How can I setup the desired version Node.js, which will be used by Jenkins by default?

Answer (score 11):

Go to: <kbd>Dashboard</kbd> → <kbd>Manage Jenkins</kbd> → <kbd>Global Tool Configuration</kbd> → <kbd>NodeJS</kbd> and pick the desired Node.js version from the combobox.

Comment: In my case nodeJS isn't listed there

Comment: @schmidlop You probably don't need the answer after 2 years, but you have to install the NodeJS plugin.

Comment: but from where it is picking node version 8, In my case it is giving node 12 (node --version output) but I have installed node 18 in my ec2 where I have installed jenkins, also I don't have nodje plugin so m confused from where it got node 12 @schmidlop

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following two lines in your pipeline

```
env.NODEJS_HOME = "${tool 'NodeJsv12.16.2'}"
env.PATH="${env.NODEJS_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

See the  example bellow

```
node {

    env.NODEJS_HOME = "${tool 'NodeJsv12.16.2'}"
    env.PATH="${env.NODEJS_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    sh 'npm --version'

    stage('Preparation') { 
         
       }
}
```